# how to I add button and text in carousel with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have an assignment where I need to use Vue.js and Quasar and I need to put buttons and text in the carousel. How can I do this? There is no example anywhere. I would be happy if you help me.

Here's my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-carousel
    swipeable
      animated
      arrows
      v-model="slide"
      infinite
      v-model:fullscreen="fullscreen"
    >
      <q-carousel-slide :name="1" img-src="https://img1-newbalance.mncdn.com/newbalance/products/uploads/banner/mainslider/550NED-NEA_desktop_2.jpg"/>
      <q-carousel-slide :name="2" img-src="https://img1-newbalance.mncdn.com/newbalance/products/uploads/banner/mainslider/2002rd-desktop.jpg"/>

    </q-carousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup () {
    return {
      slide: ref(1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put anything inside `q-carousel-slide` default slot.

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-carousel
    swipeable
      animated
      arrows
      v-model="slide"
      infinite
      v-model:fullscreen="fullscreen"
    >
      <q-carousel-slide :name="1" img-src="https://img1-newbalance.mncdn.com/newbalance/products/uploads/banner/mainslider/550NED-NEA_desktop_2.jpg" >
        <div class="q-mt-md text-center">
            Sample Text
        </div>
        <div class="q-mt-md text-center">
            <q-btn color="primary" label="Sample button" />
        </div>
      </q-carousel-slide>

      <q-carousel-slide :name="2" img-src="https://img1-newbalance.mncdn.com/newbalance/products/uploads/banner/mainslider/2002rd-desktop.jpg" />
        <div class="q-mt-md text-center">
            Sample Text
        </div>
        <div class="q-mt-md text-center">
            <q-btn color="primary" label="Sample button" />
        </div>
      </q-carousel-slide>

    </q-carousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup () {
    return {
      slide: ref(1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```